# How to get the Accelerometer data in background using core motion?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-motion

My requirement in the application is that I have to detect the steps counting from the application and this should be continue even the application running in the background. I have studied on this; normally apple doesn't allow the accelerometer data in the background but I guess using Core Motion we can achieve it.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
     Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.*/



    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]) { //Check if our iOS version supports multitasking I.E iOS 4

        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) { //Check if device supports mulitasking

            backgroundSupported = [UIDevice currentDevice].multitaskingSupported;

            UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];//Get the shared application instance

            __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task; //Create a task object
            background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {


                NSAssert(background_task == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid, nil);

                [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; //Tell the system that we are done with the tasks
                background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Set the task to be invalid
                //System will be shutting down the app at any point in time now

            }];


            //Background tasks require you to use asyncrous tasks
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                //Perform your tasks that your application requires


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if (background_task != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
                    {
                        [application endBackgroundTask:background_task];
                        background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                    }
                });
                locationManager.delegate = self;//or whatever class you have for managing location
                [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
                [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
                NSLog(@"\n\nRunning in the background!\n\n");
               // [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; //End the task so the system knows that you are done with what you need to perform
               // background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Invalidate the background_task

            });
        }
    }
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{

         CLLocation *loc = [locations lastObject];
         float latitudeMe = loc.coordinate.latitude;
         float longitudeMe = loc.coordinate.longitude;

         NSOperationQueue *theQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

         CMAccelerometerData *_returnedData = [[CMAccelerometerData alloc] init];
         CMMotionManager  *_motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];

        [_motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:theQueue withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {


            int x = _motionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration.x;
            int y = _motionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration.y;
            int z = _motionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration.z;

            NSLog(@"X: %i, Y: %i, z: %i", x, y,z);


            //[self changeFilter:[HighpassFilter class]];
            //[filter addAcceleration:acceleration];
            const float violence = 1.70;
            float magnitudeOfAcceleration = sqrt (x*x + y*y + z*z);

            //float magnitudeOfAcceleration = sqrt (filter.x*filter.x + filter.y * filter.y + filter.z * filter.z);
            BOOL shake = magnitudeOfAcceleration > violence;
            if (shake)
            {
                step++;
            }
             NSUserDefaults *defalut = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defalut setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",step] forKey:@"Stepscounting"];

        }];

}
```

Can any one help me where I am wrong?

**I have already added in plist file " Required background modes-> and at item 0 choose App registers for location updates".**

Comment: Does the didUpdateLocations gets called at all ? You're asking for significant changes so you'll have to walk a couple of blocks before getting a callback I think.

Comment: @Dave, yes i am getting the location coordinates on location update. didUpdateLocations gets called when we walk.The problem is that i am not getting the right steps counting.